# What is the general term for Mouse Listener?

Tags: mouseevent, mouse, mouselistener

In Java, they use the term "Listener" to refer to the objects that are used to handle mouse events.

What is the general term for these kind of objects in event-driven GUI programming ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of search, I think the most general term for this kind of objects is : Mouse Event Handler.